# Type hint for a list of string with 0 or more items in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a list which can be like this:

```
a_list = ["apple"]
```

or

```
a_list = []
```

In this case, type-hint can be  `List[str]` or `List[Optional[str]]`. Which is the appropriate type-hint for this variable and why?

Thanks!

Comment: `List[str]` if you absolutely need a list, otherwise `Sequence[str]` is more general. `Optional` is not intended to be used like that, but it means that the items of the list can be of type `str` or `None`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List[str]` includes all lists of strings, including the empty list. (From a typing perspective, an empty list of type `List[str]` is distinct from an empty list of type `List[int]`).

`Optional[str]` is shorthand for `Union[None, str]`, so `List[Optional[str]]` is the type of lists that can contain `str` values and `None`s, not the type of list that may or may not have a `str` value.

Answer (score 1):

As of python 3.10 `list` will do just fine:

```py
# 3.10 and above
my_list: list[str] = []

# earlier versions of python
from typing import List
ma_list: List[str] = []
```

Comment: _So, my_list can contain str or None._  The question is about a List contain zero or one/more strings. Your answer does _not_ seem to cover the topic of the question.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, as of Python 3.10. A list can contain 0 elements, hence None, or it can contain strings. Thus `list[str|None]`.

Comment: @ccasimiro9444 `None` does not mean "no elements inside a list", it means "an element that has no value". So `[None]` is a `list[None]` and `['123']` is a `list[str]`, but `[]` can be any `list`.